# Orphaned question

Tags: support, linked-accounts

I asked a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235214/can-i-overload-part-for-specific-heads-a-la-overloaded-array-subscripting) on Mathematica Stack Exchange.

The system sent me an email, and in it I clicked "Set Your Password" and followed that process to set up my account.  Yet, the question I originally asked has associated user ID of [75893](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/75893/josh-helzer) and the account that was created (and that I now have access to) has a user ID of [75896](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/75896/josh-helzer).

So my original question is orphaned - I have no access to it.  Namely, I have no access to mark an answer as accepted.

This is very frustrating and feels like a bug.

How do I get access to the first account that is associated with my question?  I obviously have access to the email address associated with the question, but any login links take me to the shadow account that was created (and that is not associated with any questions)...

### Update 1:

This question is a duplicate of the indicated question in the sense of *remedy*, but not in the sense of *cause*:  the underlying cause of a first-time user's anonymous question-asking and the resultant possible schism come account-creation time remains unaddressed.  See discussion under @shadow-10-years-wizard's answer.

Comment: @sonic-the-k-day-hedgehog possibly - I've submitted the contact form request to merge the two accounts...

Comment: @sonic-the-k-day-hedgehog that worked for gaining access to my original question.  Thanks!  But it still seems to me like there is a bug in the ask-a-question-and-then-create-the-account process, which resulted in this problem originally...

Answer (score 2):

When you ask a question as a guest, your credentials are stored in a cookie on your browser.

As long as you have the cookie, and use the same browser profile, you should be posting with that same account you created as a guest, which is called "Unregistered account".

You can register the account via email, but it can result in a new account in such cases, as far as I can tell:

- You cleared your cookies before clicking the link in the email, thus losing access to the original guest account, so the system couldn't tell it's really your account.
- You opened the link from the email in a different browser profile, which doesn't have the cookie.

Neither of those is a bug. The ability to merge the accounts is enough, and pretty simple. Good luck!

Comment: I would argue that the system-generated email should contain enough of an identifier in the "claim"/register URL itself so that loss of cookies doesn't result in what I experienced, no?

Comment: @JoshHelzer that's a major security issue. Suppose you send the link to someone by mistake, or paste it somewhere... you really want people to gain full access to your account? Link alone must never be enough, it must come with another validation method.

Comment: Remember the context.  An anonymous/unregistered question is posted, yet I **provide** an email address.  The system then sends a link to the provided email to claim/register the question with a fully-fledged account.  Seems pretty obvious and a common first-time-user use case, no?

And there is no security implication whatsoever - if I forward the content of my email, then obviously whoever receives it will have access to its contents.  That is not something worth worrying about.

Comment: @Josh OK, so you can post a feature request asking to change this.

Comment: Being a new user, what I've managed to figure out is the best I've got.  Perhaps you'd care to point me to the relevant form?  Alternatively, you could volunteer to reproduce the behavior and champion it as a bug!  :P